# android PPM encoder audio library

Tags: android, audio, remote-control, modulation

I need to implement audio PPM (Pulse Position Modulation) on android

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-position_modulation

I want to output PPM from the audio output of the smartphone.
The final scope is to create a joystick for radiocontrol. but this library may have many future purposes (follow me, lightbridge,  etc.etc.).
The radios commonly have a PPM output. Transmitters (and pc flight simulators) commonly have PPM input.
My scope is to replace the radio with an android device.
I wish to know if there is some piece of code ready to use or should i start from scratch?

EDIT: I found some points where to start

1) smartpropplus is a windows software that receives PPM audio and decodes it
http://sourceforge.net/p/smartpropoplus/code/HEAD/tree/SPP4/

2) this is how PPM is structured: http://www.aerodesign.de/peter/2000/PCM/PCM_PPM_eng.html#Anker144123

3) this is a easy image that explains how the signal is structured: http://www.aerodesign.de/peter/2000/PCM/frame_ppm.gif

I calculated that sampling the audio signal at 22000Hz will be sufficient to achieve a good resolution for each channel (22 steps for each channel)

Note: if you are interested in receiving ppm audio signal, you need the android ppm decoder class that you can find here: [android PPM decoder audio library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653684/android-ppm-decoder-audio-library)

Comment: Hello! Do you make this work? I have working prototype in Arduino and i want to adapt code for Android. Since my arduino code works, i can compare wave generated with my code and wave of your code. It looks like some differencies in waves but i dont know how to fix this in your code.

Comment: @striker, i still didn't received my new android tablet, and since my phone has a hardware problem on the audio output, i'm not able to test the code.

Comment: share your compare here, may be we can fix it just looking at the code. i wrote it very fast and then i had to stop cause i found that my phone has a audio problem.

Comment: it will be really interesting also the PPMdecoder...but it is better to do one step at time

Comment: this is feed from arduino: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1999619/images/ppm/arduino.jpg

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1999619/images/ppm/java.jpg this is java

Comment: @striker, Is the image java.jpg related to my code? Today i found this: http://www.gcer.net/scoring/papers/UnivLjubljianaSlovenia_Jaklic_soundservo-F.pdf

Comment: if the java.jpg is obtained with my code, this is strange, it should be possible to identify the problem by changing part of the doInBackground subroutine. Anyway the signal level shouldn't be a problem. Also the previous link points to a guy who still solved this code.

Comment: I wrote an email to that guy, asking him to share its code.

Comment: any luck on this? I rewrite your code and now i see valid PPM signal on my Turnigy9x but only one time when i switch it on. Give me your email address to share the code

Comment: @striker are you using the doinbackground sub with the "while(started)" loop like i did in my example? If you don't use that loop the doinbackground will be executed just once. Paste Your code on pastebin.com and share the link

Comment: @stricker i was reading the audiotrack.write method and actually it is possible that i did a mistake. It seems that the third parameter of the write method should be the blocking/not blocking. Check it up:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html.   as i said, actually i don't have a smartphone neither a PC, i have only chocolate and panettone

Comment: ..it is missing the fourth parameter...

Comment: with some refactoring http://pastebin.com/AHAGcj4Q

Comment: @striker you said that Your code runs only for a single loop. Add a debug to see if the while loop continues to run or if the loop stops. Also check if a error is catched by the try catch structure by adding a break while in debug. Your code seems to be correct. You are using a 44khz but this implies more processing resources while a standard radio control doesn't use more than 20 steps for the throttle stick, so i suppose it is not needed 44khz, but 22khz is enough

Comment: i made some corrections to your code:

1)i want to compile for android from2.2to4.2then i must specify the data type of ArrayList,in detail,you wrote "Arraylist<>(.." and i modified it in "Arraylist<Float>(.."

2)you made a big mistake;you setted the size of the audio buffer using the size of the ppm frame,but this is wrong,infact you must always ask to android which is the minimum buffer size,and then use that size to compose the signal to generate,by replicating many times the ppm frame.I suspect that my code has a similar error,not considering with the proper attenction these 2 dimensions.

Comment: 3)another mistake is to fix the sampling frequency, cause it is not supported by some devices.

Comment: 4) another error is that you allow the user to set the number of channels but then inside the while loop you use:" for (int channel = 0; channel < 8; channel++) {..."

Comment: 1) it seems better to use float[] instead ArrayList. 2) do in u have some documentation about it? I will try maybe this is an issue

Comment: 2) do you have * 4) nice, i will fix that

Comment: 2) i will post my working code, then you can find the relative documentation, by searching "streaming buffer and write buffer for android audiotrack" on google.  4) i fixed by leaving 8 as the number of channels because i read on wikipedia that 8 is the maximum number of channels for ppm encoding.

Comment: @striker i posted my code as a solution, check it and let me know what do you think. I used your code as a base, then i modified it. Anyway as you can read, i wasn't able to let it work with a real device. i was able just to use it with smartpropoplus, so i think that the implementation is correct. But i wish we can let it work also with commercial devices like the dji lightbridge.

Comment: let's better debug the encoder class, then we can start to write the DECODER class....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I made a working example for ppm encoder class.

This is how i tested it:

1)recording the generated sound with a PC i can see on "wavepad editor" the waveform and it corresponds to what we need.

2) recording the audio output of the smartphone with a pc and analyzing the audio signal with the software "smartpropoplus" and its debug utilities, i can correctly control the PPM channels with my android app.

3) I connected the phone to a PPM receiver (DJI Lightbridge) but the signal is not correctly received. I suspect that the signal level is not the one expected by the dji device. I will wait your feedback comments, but until that moment, i suspect that i did the best that we can do with android.

---

NOTE:
if you want to use my complete example, you need to use the file joystickView.jar in order to control the channels with a graphical joypad.
this is how to use it:

1)download the jar file from this link: https://github.com/downloads/zerokol/JoystickView/joystickview.jar

2) Create a folder called "libs" on the root of your project and place the JAR file into this folder.

---

Now you can test my app.

### These are the files of my test app:

file AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tr3ma.PPMtestProject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tr3ma.PPMtestProject.Test"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
     >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

file activity_test.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stick1VerticalLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="stick1Vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stick1HorizontalLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="stick1Horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stick2VerticalLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="stick2Vertical"  />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stick2HorizontalLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="stick2Horizontal"  />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>

    <com.zerokol.views.JoystickView
        android:id="@+id/joystickViewLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <com.zerokol.views.JoystickView
        android:id="@+id/joystickViewRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end" />

</LinearLayout>




 </LinearLayout>
```

file Test.java

```
 package com.tr3ma.PPMtestProject;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;

 import com.tr3ma.PPMtestProject.R;
 import com.zerokol.views.JoystickView;
 import com.zerokol.views.JoystickView.OnJoystickMoveListener;

 public class Test extends Activity {

 PPMEncoder ppmencoder;

 private TextView stick1VerticalLabel;
 private TextView stick1HorizontalLabel;
 private TextView stick2VerticalLabel;
 private TextView stick2HorizontalLabel;
 // Importing as others views
 private JoystickView joystickLeft;
 private JoystickView joystickRight;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);



    ppmencoder=new PPMEncoder(this);

    //start the generation of the signal through the speakers
    int result=ppmencoder.startGeneration();
    if (result!=0){
        //error occoured, something went wrong
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Error during audio signal generation. Error Number " + result);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }
        });
        alert.show();

    }

    stick1VerticalLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stick1VerticalLabel);
    stick1HorizontalLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stick1HorizontalLabel);
    stick2VerticalLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stick2VerticalLabel);
    stick2HorizontalLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stick2HorizontalLabel);
    // referring as others views
    joystickLeft = (JoystickView) findViewById(R.id.joystickViewLeft);
    joystickRight = (JoystickView) findViewById(R.id.joystickViewRight);

    // Listener of events, it'll return the angle in graus and power in percents
    // return to the direction of the moviment
    joystickLeft.setOnJoystickMoveListener(new OnJoystickMoveListener() {
         @Override
         public void onValueChanged(int angle, int power, int direction) {

             //scompose the vector
             float stickVertical=(float) Math.sin((Math.PI/180) * angle)*power; //values between +100 and -100
             stickVertical=stickVertical+(float)100; //values between 0 and 200
             stickVertical=(float)stickVertical*(float)((float)255/(float)200); //values between 0 and 255


             float stickHorizontal=(float) Math.cos((Math.PI/180) * angle)*power; //values between +100 and -100
             stickHorizontal=stickHorizontal+(float)100; //values between 0 and 200
             stickHorizontal=stickHorizontal*(float)((float)255/(float)200); //values between 0 and 255

             stick1VerticalLabel.setText("channel1:" + String.valueOf(stickVertical));
             stick1HorizontalLabel.setText("channel2:" + String.valueOf(stickHorizontal));

             ppmencoder.setChannelValue(1, stickVertical);
             ppmencoder.setChannelValue(2, stickHorizontal);


         }
    }, JoystickView.DEFAULT_LOOP_INTERVAL);

    joystickRight.setOnJoystickMoveListener(new OnJoystickMoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChanged(int angle, int power, int direction) {

         //scompose the vector
            //scompose the vector
         float stickVertical=(float) Math.sin((Math.PI/180) * angle)*power; //values between +100 and -100
         stickVertical=stickVertical+(float)100; //values between 0 and 200
         stickVertical=(float)stickVertical*(float)((float)255/(float)200); //values between 0 and 255


         float stickHorizontal=(float) Math.cos((Math.PI/180) * angle)*power; //values between +100 and -100
         stickHorizontal=stickHorizontal+(float)100; //values between 0 and 200
         stickHorizontal=stickHorizontal*(float)((float)255/(float)200); //values between 0 and 255

         stick2VerticalLabel.setText("channel3:" + String.valueOf(stickVertical));
         stick2HorizontalLabel.setText("channel4:" + String.valueOf(stickHorizontal));

         ppmencoder.setChannelValue(3, stickVertical);
         ppmencoder.setChannelValue(4, stickHorizontal);


        }
   }, JoystickView.DEFAULT_LOOP_INTERVAL);


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    int result=ppmencoder.stopGeneration();
    if (result!=0){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Error while stopping the audio generation. Error number " + result);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
}
 }
```

file PPMEncoder.java  (this is the class requested on the original question)

```
 package com.tr3ma.PPMtestProject;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.media.AudioFormat;
 import android.media.AudioManager;
 import android.media.AudioTrack;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;

 public class PPMEncoder
 {
public int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
public int ppmFrameBufferSize = (int)(SAMPLE_RATE * 0.0225); // 22KHz * 22,5ms that it is the duration of a frame ppm
public int audioBufferSize;

private ArrayList<Float> channelValues;

AudioManager audioManager;
StreamPPMSignalTask streamPPMSignalTask;

private boolean started;

public PPMEncoder(Context context)
{
    audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    //set volume to max
    //audioManager=(AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int tmpVol = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);    
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, tmpVol, 0);



    channelValues = new ArrayList<Float>(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        channelValues.add((float)0.68181818);
    }
}

public int startGeneration()
{
    try {


        audioBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)*2;

        if (audioBufferSize<=0 ) return -2;

        started = true;

        streamPPMSignalTask = new StreamPPMSignalTask();
        streamPPMSignalTask.execute();
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}

public int stopGeneration()
{
    try {
        started = false;

        streamPPMSignalTask.cancel(true);
        streamPPMSignalTask = null;
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}


private int timeToSamples(float time)
{
    //time is expressed in milliseconds
    return (int)Math.round(time * 0.001 * SAMPLE_RATE);
}

public void setChannelValue(int channel, float value)
{
    channelValues.set(channel - 1, (float)0.68181818+(float)1.0 * ((float)value/(float)255));
}

public int setSamplingRate(int freq) {
    //we can change the sampling frequency in case the default one is not supported
    try {
        SAMPLE_RATE=freq;

        ppmFrameBufferSize = (int)(SAMPLE_RATE* 0.0225); // 22KHz * 22,5ms

        audioBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) * 2;

        if (audioBufferSize<=0 ) return -2;

        started=false;
        stopGeneration();
        startGeneration();

        //frame=new byte[streamBufferSize];
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}


public class StreamPPMSignalTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Double, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        AudioTrack ppmTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, audioBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        //set volume of audioplayer to max
        ppmTrack.setStereoVolume((float) 1.0, (float) 1.0);

        if (ppmTrack.getPlayState() != AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {
            ppmTrack.play();
        }

        //feed the speakers with our audio, by continuously send the PPM frame
        int tempBound;
        while (started) {
            try {
                short[] frame = new short[ppmFrameBufferSize];

                int i = 0;
                tempBound = i + timeToSamples((float)0.3);
                for (;i < tempBound; i += 1) {
                    frame[i] = Short.MIN_VALUE;
                }

                for (int channel = 0; channel < 8; channel++) {
                    tempBound = i + timeToSamples(channelValues.get(channel));
                    for (;i < tempBound; i += 1) {
                        frame[i] = Short.MAX_VALUE;
                    }

                    tempBound= i + timeToSamples((float)0.3);
                    for (;i < tempBound; i += 1) {
                        frame[i] = Short.MIN_VALUE;
                    }
                }

                for (;i < frame.length; i += 1) {
                    frame[i] = Short.MAX_VALUE;
                }

                //send the frame
                ppmTrack.write(frame, 0, frame.length);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
 }
```

End notes:

1) as you can see the 2 joysticks moves only 4 channels, but it is clear that you can add another 2 joystick controls on the activity in order to move all 8 channels.

2) credit goes to this site where you can see how it is made the joystickControl http://www.zerokol.com/2012/03/joystickview-custom-android-view-to.html in case you want to customize it. I wish to do it but i had no time. today i spent the entire day to write this post.

Comment: Thanks for smartpropoplus, i also install it and can debug. So, old code works too with smartpropoplus. New code also work. But dont work on my Turnigy with same issues: turn off turnigy, set channel vaues, connect audiojack to trainer port of turnigy and open channels displays in menu and i see changes!

Comment: I never used that way. Are you connecting the smartphone to turnigy radio? I have a cheap turnigy 9x, can I do this with mine? Where do you read channels value?

Comment: You wrote that on the turnigy you have the same issues but you wasn't clear because you also wrote that on the turnigy display you can see channels received by the  android app

Comment: yeah i use minijack-minijack cable to connect to my turnigy9x. After go to "menu - func settings - trainer" and activate trainer for channel 7 and 8. In "menu - func settings - display" you can see your transmitter channel values (move the sticks).

Comment: So i open android app, set ch7,8 values, connect my tx with audiocable, go to "menu - display" and see values changes on my channels. If i change values in app i cant see any changes. If i turn off the tx, change values and go to "menu-display" again i see changes on channels.

Comment: @striker Read here, also the comments: http://www.andrewhazelden.com/blog/2011/08/analyzing-rc-radio-ppm-signals/   you can see that turnigy9x uses 5V input. Use the suggested level adapter board or reflash the turnigy with the firmware of the turnigy er9xx. It seems that spektrum and other brands uses 3 volt level. Afaik audio max level is 3V

Comment: @striker join this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653684/android-ppm-decoder-audio-library  and vote up these questions and solutions if you like